# According to Pentecostals and Charismatics, what are concrete practical ways by which Christians can be filled (and stay filled) with the Holy Spirit?

Tags: christian-living, pneumatology, pentecostalism, spirituality, charismatic

The concept of "being filled" with the Holy Spirit is mentioned multiple times in the New Testament, and according to the book of Acts it appears to have been a crucial aspect of the early Christian life.

According to **Pentecostals and Charismatics**:

- What does it mean to be "filled" with the Holy Spirit?
- What are concrete and practical ways by which Christians can be filled (and stay filled) with the Holy Spirit?

---

Other perspectives:

- [According to Catholicism, what are concrete and practical ways by which Christians can be filled (and stay filled) with the Holy Spirit?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86596/50422)
- [According to non-Pentecostal Protestants, what are concrete practical ways by which Christians can be filled (and stay filled) with the Holy Spirit?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86595/50422)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1 What does it mean to be filled with the Holy Spirit?

The term "Filled with the holy spirit" firstly appeared in the new testament in the verse below:

> Acts 2:2 And suddenly there came a sound from heaven as of a **rushing mighty wind**, and it **filled** all the house where they were sitting.

This is the story of Pentecost Day. The disciples were gathering in the upper room. At this point, it's not clear, what or who fills them. Let's continue

> Acts 2:4 And **they were all filled with the Holy Ghost**, and **began to speak with other tongues**, as the Spirit gave them utterance.

It's very clear through this verse that to be filled with Holy Spirit has a connection with speaking with other tongues or simply we said "speaking in tongues". The sign of someone filled with Holy Spirit can be directly seen when they speak in tongues.

### 2 What are concrete and practical ways by which Christians can be filled (and stay filled) with the Holy Spirit?

Simple answer: use speaking in tongues especially in private or group prayers

> 1 Cor 14:14 For if **I pray in an unknown tongue, my spirit prayeth**, but my understanding is unfruitful.

> 1 Cor 14:15 What is it then? **I will pray with the spirit, and I will pray with the understanding** also: I will sing with the spirit, and I will sing with the understanding also.

We can pray in our language which means we pray with our understanding. But we can also use speaking in tongues in our prayer. In that way, you let the Holy Spirit pray with you. This is the practical way to always be filled with the Holy Spirit.

Even Apostle Paul said that:

> 1 Cor 14:18 I thank my God, **I speak with tongues more than ye all**

### 3 Regarding prophesying

> Acts 19:6 And when Paul had laid his hands upon them, the Holy Ghost came on them; and **they spake with tongues**, and **prophesied.**

I only find one verse that has a connection between prophesying and speaking in tongues. In that verse, they speak in tongues and then they prophesied. In my experience, we can give some prophecy to our brother and sister in the church without any speaking in tongues. If we are speaking in tongues, it will become a prophecy if there is someone who has a gift to interpret the tongues.

So the conclusion we can use some logical statements like below :

- If we are filled with the Holy Spirit, there is a sign of speaking in tongues.
- If we are speaking in tongues and there is some interpretation, it will become prophecy
- If we are prophesying, it does not always direct sign of filled with the Holy Spirit

### 4 Regarding boldness in preaching

> Acts 4: 31 And when they had prayed, the place was shaken where they were assembled together; and **they were all filled with the Holy Ghost**, and **they spake the word of God with boldness**.

In this verse, after they are filled with the Holy Spirit, they preach the gospel with boldness. If we just refer to this verse, we will be trapped to the conclusion that the sign of filled with the Holy Spirit is preaching with boldness

But we can also see that in Acts 2 that Apostle Peter preached the gospel with boldness after speaking in tongues happen as the sign of filled with Holy Spirit. Another example

> Acts 10:44 While Peter yet spake these words, **the Holy Ghost fell on all them** (similar with Acts 2:2) which heard the word.

> Acts 10: 45 And they of the circumcision which believed were astonished, as many as came with Peter, because that on the Gentiles also was poured out the gift of the Holy Ghost.

> Acts 10:46 **For they heard them speak with tongues**, and magnify God.

So we have four similar stories right now

1. Acts 2 Filled with the holy spirit > Speaking in tongues > Preach with boldness
2. Acts 4 Filled with the holy spirit > Preach with boldness
3. Acts 10 Filled with the holy spirit > Speaking in tongues > magnify God
4. Acts 19 Filled with the holy spirit > Speaking in tongues > prophesying

Because we have 3 examples that are filled with the holy spirit will follow with speaking in tongues, it will be safer if we assume Acts 4 should actually follow speaking in tongues. We don't know why Luke the author of Acts did not write it on Acts 4 but we can not neglect three other stories mentioning speaking with tongues.

You can also read the story of Smith Wigglesworth. He preaches the gospel with boldness even though he does not have any sign of speaking in tongues. After he filled with Holy Spirit, speaking in tongues, he preached the gospel even greater and even bolder.

*So preaching the gospel with boldness is not directly a sign that he/she has been filled with the Holy Spirit*

### Further Notes

We need to know the difference between being filled with the Holy Spirit and having the holy spirit in our hearts. I will stop here to know your response first.

Comment: `The sign of someone filled with Holy Spirit can be directly seen when they speak in tongues.` - what about prophesying or boldness for preaching?

Comment: Hi ! Allow me to explain in another post answer below because I feel the comments feature here are kinda limited to explain. I was sleeping last night so I can only answer your comments just now. Hope it will give you definite answer

Comment: I know someone who was taught, in a classroom setting, how to speak in tongues.

Comment: I don't know clearly what kind of teaching they have which @MikeBorden is mentioning above. As far as I did in my ministry, I did not teach how to speak in tongues, I just explained my understanding on speaking in tongues and then if I was allowed I would pray together with the participants to receive the baptism of the Holy Spirit (a.k.a filled with the spirit). Just two cents from me. Peace.

Comment: "It's very clear through this verse that to be filled with Holy Spirit has a connection with speaking with other tongues or simply we said "speaking in tongues". **The sign of someone filled with Holy Spirit can be directly seen when they speak in tongues.**" Are you referring to 'glossalalia' here (the uttering of unintelligible, language-like sounds)? Because ...

Comment: ... Acts 2:6-8 continues "because each one heard them speaking his own language. 7 Astounded and amazed, they asked, “Are not all these men who are speaking Galileans? 8 How is it then that each of us hears them in his own native language?" This isn't a description of glossalalia, it's of xenoglossia.

Comment: Yes my friend @OneGodtheFather if we read the Acts 2:6-8, we are referring to xenoglossia. Furthermore, the gift glossalalia and xenoglossia, both of them are inspired by the Holy Spirit. I have experience in my ministry, when my friends are filled with Holy Spirit they speak glossalalia and the others speak xenoglossia.

Comment: @FendySion04 You seem to be conflating them in your answer. These are very different phenomena.  I've heard lots of glossalalia from Charismatics and Pentecostals. It's not difficult to make sounds like glossalalia. I've never heard of a single instance of xenoglossia occurring among people I know. Acts 2 is referring to xenoglossia, yet you're claiming glossalalia is a sign someone is filled with the HS based on Acts 2. ?

Comment: Hi @OneGodtheFather correct me if I'm wrong. Acts 2 : 4 which I quote as an answer did not mention glossalalia or xenoglossia. [link](https://www.abarim-publications.com/DictionaryG/g/g-l-om-s-s-a.html) . In greek it only said laleo hetero Glossa (speak other tongues). That's why I use the Acts 2:4 to convey the message to all reader that the sign of someone filled with HS is speaking in tongues whether glossalalia or xenoglossia. The terminology glossalalia and xenoglossia are proposed lately at the end of 18th century (I'm still looking the link to put here)

Comment: Acts 2:6-12 explain that the believers in the upper room speaking in other multiple nation languages known to the people visiting Jerusalem. That’s why people tend to refer this as xenoglossia (xeno = foreign). But it doesn’t mean the experience of speaking in tongues (as the sign of filled with HS) is limited only for xenoglossia. [link](https://ebible.com/questions/21252-what-is-xenoglossia-and-is-it-biblical)

Comment: recall that xenoglossia does not need anyone having the gift to interpret speaking in tongues. The letter from Paul in 1 Corinthian 12, 14 mentioning about someone who has the gift to interpret speaking in tongues. It implies that there is a another kind of speaking in tongues, other than xenoglossia which does not need any interpreter, which now we call glossalalia.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather said “it’s not difficult to make sounds like glossalalia”. Everyone is welcomed to try to make that sound like glossalalia, but will there be anyone who can interpret? I doubt any glossalalia imitation can have some interpretation from he / she who are given the gift to interpret the speaking in tongues.

Bonus : I witness my friend speaking in Arabic even though he never learn any (xenoglossia). We were trying to explain the gospel to a muslim man and after we pray together, the man said that he heard my friend speaks very clear Arabic words.